# Relative path problem when including css and js in a html page

Tags: php, html, web

My server web directory structure is like

```
/www/site1/
    js/
    css/
    partial/
          -head.php
          -footer.php
    view/
         -page1.php
    -index.php

/www/site2/
```

head.html includes js files like

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

head.php file is included in index.php and view/page1.php.

It works fine on index.php but not on page1.php because of the path of js files. On index.php path becomes like

```
/www/site1/js/jquery.min.js
```

On page1.php path becomes

```
/www/site1/view/js/jquery.min.js
```

How to include js on head.php so that it works fine when included in index and page1

Comment: the relative path needs to be relative to the url that serves it - not the file it's in, why not just use an absolute path : `/js/jquery.min.js` ?

Comment: you can use like this say <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: use '.' since it is a parents sibling

Comment: @Pete Yes i also tried it, but it becomes like **/www/js/** instead of **/www/site1/js/**

Comment: Then your server is set up wrong and this is probably a server question - or just use `/site1/js/.....js` if you need it from site1

Answer (score 0):

Try add slash to source

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes i also tried it, but it becomes like **/www/js/** instead of **/www/site1/js/**